# My Notebook has no monitor listed in Windows 7 Device Manager

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display

Self explanatory, my notebook has no monitor listed in windows 7 Device Manager. Even the category doesn't exists. Video is Intel HD, which does show up. I've come to this situation when I was investigating TeamViewer Black video driver not installing. Since no monitor shows up, how can I update drivers and etc? Also how the computer works without a monitor, even a standard driver?

Comment: Have you got any restore points?

Comment: No, but it's been this "no monitor" situation since forever. I've used the PC for more than a year like this with no problems.